# Compare .NET's AjaxOptions class with jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I've just read an article detailing the functionality of MS's Ajax.BeginForm (http://www.aspnetpro.com/articles/2009/06/asp200906de_f/asp200906de_f.asp) and. Looking at the AjaxOptions members i find it very easy to understand the various functions that can be applied to a form submission.

Just by looking at the table really help my head grasp the larger picture. I'd like to get that same grok for equivalent functions when jQuery is used for Ajax form submissions.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same sort of data can be found on [the API documentation page for Jquery.Ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax)